# Implementing Infinite Scrolling in Google App Engine

Tags: jquery, python, google-app-engine

First I want to state that I asked a similar question before, however I would like to give this question more direction. As a noob to python, app engine and especially jquery, this is turning out to be quite a daunting task. I was wondering if someone could please point me in the right direction (perhaps a way to do this in app engine itself), and maybe even be so kind as to outline what I should do here.

The following is the code that gets posts in my profile page:

What I have now is a Query object:

```
 posts = db.GqlQuery("select * from Profile_Comments WHERE name_of_profile =:1 order by date_created desc", profile_id)
```

And a for loop in my jinja template that gets the posts:

```
{% for post_tmp in posts %}

        {{post_tmp.post.replace('\r\n', '<br>') | safe }}

{%  endfor %}
```

Thank you very very much! And sorry for the pseudo re-post!

Edit - Entire Profile Handler (the template is posted above... its a simple for loop):

```
  class Profile(MainHandler):
    def get(self, profile_id):
        u = User.by_name(profile_id.lower())
        if not u:
            self.redirect('/')
        if self.user and profile_id:
            current_user = self.user.name
            name1 = ''
            friend_name = ''
            team_imagee = ''
            key = ''
            monthss = ''
            yearss = ''
            dayss = ''
            countryss = ''
            team_imagee2 = ''
            imgs2 = ''
            imgs = ''
            key2 = ''
            name22 = ''
            name2 = ''
            handless = ''
            msgg = ''
            imgs  = db.GqlQuery("select * from Profile_Images WHERE name =:1", profile_id)
            imgs2  = db.GqlQuery("select * from Profile_Images WHERE name =:1", current_user)
            team_name  = db.GqlQuery("select * from Teams WHERE name =:1", profile_id)
            team_images  = db.GqlQuery("select * from Teamimg WHERE user =:1", profile_id)
            team_images2  = db.GqlQuery("select * from Teamimg WHERE user =:1", current_user)
            friends  = db.GqlQuery("select * from Friends WHERE name =:1 order by added_date desc limit 10", profile_id)
            posts = db.GqlQuery("select * from Profile_Comments WHERE name_of_profile =:1 order by date_created desc", profile_id)
            name2 = db.GqlQuery("select * from User WHERE name =:1", profile_id)
            month = db.GqlQuery("select * from User WHERE name =:1", profile_id)
            day = db.GqlQuery("select * from User WHERE name =:1", profile_id)
            year = db.GqlQuery("select * from User WHERE name =:1", profile_id)
            country = db.GqlQuery("select * from User WHERE name =:1", profile_id)
            handle  = db.GqlQuery("select * from Handle WHERE name =:1", profile_id)
            rating = db.GqlQuery("select * from Rating WHERE name_of_profile =:1", profile_id)
            profile_msg = db.GqlQuery("select * from Profile_Msg WHERE name =:1", profile_id)
            for handles in handle:
                handless = handles.handle_name
            for months in month:
                monthss = months.month
            for countrys in country:
                countryss = countrys.country
            for days in day:
                dayss = days.day
            for years in year:
                yearss = years.year
            for clan in team_name:
                    name1 = clan.team_name_anycase
            for clan in team_name:
                    name2 = clan.team_name
            for image in team_images:
                team_imagee = image.key()
            for image2 in team_images2:
                team_imagee2 = image2.key()
            for img in imgs:
                key = img.key()
            for img2 in imgs2:
                key2 = img2.key()
            for msg in profile_msg:
                    msgg = msg.msg       
            self.render('profile.html', msg = msgg, team_name2 = name2, handle_var = handless,  imgs = imgs, team_img2 = team_imagee2, profile_image_posted = key2, posts = posts, profile_id = profile_id, country_var = countryss, day_var = dayss, year_var = yearss, month_var = monthss, current_user = current_user, friends = friends, team_img = team_imagee, team_name = name1, profile_image = key, username = self.user.name, email = self.user.email, firstname = self.user.first_name, last_name = self.user.last_name, country = self.user.country)
        else:
            self.redirect('/register')


    def post(self, profile_id):
        if self.user and profile_id:
            current_user = self.user.name
            name1 = ''
            friend_name = ''
            team_imagee = ''
            key = ''
            monthss = ''
            yearss = ''
            dayss = ''
            countryss = ''
            team_imagee2 = ''
            imgs2 = ''
            imgs = ''
            key2 = ''
            name22 = ''
            name2 = ''
            handless = ''
            msgg = ''
            imgs  = db.GqlQuery("select * from Profile_Images WHERE name =:1", profile_id)
            imgs2  = db.GqlQuery("select * from Profile_Images WHERE name =:1", current_user)
            team_name  = db.GqlQuery("select * from Teams WHERE name =:1", profile_id)
            team_images  = db.GqlQuery("select * from Teamimg WHERE user =:1", profile_id)
            team_images2  = db.GqlQuery("select * from Teamimg WHERE user =:1", current_user)
            friends  = db.GqlQuery("select * from Friends WHERE name =:1 order by added_date desc limit 10", profile_id)
            posts = db.GqlQuery("select * from Profile_Comments WHERE name_of_profile =:1 order by date_created desc", profile_id)
            name2 = db.GqlQuery("select * from User WHERE name =:1", profile_id)
            month = db.GqlQuery("select * from User WHERE name =:1", profile_id)
            day = db.GqlQuery("select * from User WHERE name =:1", profile_id)
            year = db.GqlQuery("select * from User WHERE name =:1", profile_id)
            country = db.GqlQuery("select * from User WHERE name =:1", profile_id)
            handle  = db.GqlQuery("select * from Handle WHERE name =:1", profile_id)
            for handles in handle:
                handless = handles.handle_name
            for months in month:
                monthss = months.month
            for countrys in country:
                countryss = countrys.country
            for days in day:
                dayss = days.day
            for years in year:
                yearss = years.year
            for clan in team_name:
                    name1 = clan.team_name_anycase
            for clan in team_name:
                    name2 = clan.team_name
            for image in team_images:
                team_imagee = image.key()
            for image2 in team_images2:
                team_imagee2 = image2.key()
            for img in imgs:
                key = img.key()
            for img2 in imgs2:
                key2 = img2.key()
            profile_submit_comment=''
            post_check = self.request.get('profile_submit_comment')
            if self.request.get('delete'):
                the_post = self.request.get('delete')
                q = Profile_Comments.get_by_id(int(the_post), parent=None)
                db.delete(q)
                error = "Comment successfully deleted."
                self.render('profile.html', handle_var = handless, team_name2 = name2, error = error, imgs = imgs, team_img2 = team_imagee2, profile_image_posted = key2, posts = posts, profile_id = profile_id, country_var = countryss, day_var = dayss, year_var = yearss, month_var = monthss, current_user = current_user, friends = friends, team_img = team_imagee, team_name = name1, profile_image = key, username = self.user.name, email = self.user.email, firstname = self.user.first_name, last_name = self.user.last_name, country = self.user.country)
#            if self.request.get('edit'):
#                the_post = self.request.get('edit')
#                q = Profile_Comments.get_by_id(int(the_post), parent=None)
#                db.delete(q)
#                self.redirect('/profile/%s' %profile_id)
            elif not post_check:
                error = "You cannot submit empty posts."
                self.render('profile.html', team_name2 = name2, error = error, imgs = imgs, team_img2 = team_imagee2, profile_image_posted = key2, posts = posts, profile_id = profile_id, country_var = countryss, day_var = dayss, year_var = yearss, month_var = monthss, current_user = current_user, friends = friends, team_img = team_imagee, team_name = name1, profile_image = key, username = self.user.name, email = self.user.email, firstname = self.user.first_name, last_name = self.user.last_name, country = self.user.country)
            elif self.request.get("profile_submit_comment") != '':
                profile_comments = Profile_Comments (name_of_submitted = self.user.name, name_of_profile = profile_id)
                commentupl = self.request.get("profile_submit_comment")
                profile_comments.post = (commentupl)
                profile_comments.put()
                self.redirect('/profile/%s' %profile_id)
```

Comment: Can you post the rest of the code from your handler? (Starting with where you define the GET function all the way to where you pass `posts` to the template). You'll need to use Javascript to request more posts and insert new page elements to display them. Your template only handles the first set of posts. One thing that helped me when I learned this was to start by adding a "More" button at the bottom that works without Javascript (which is good design anyways). Once that's in place, implementing infinite scrolling is just like getting Javascript to click the button for you.

Comment: Hm, ok that makes it a little clearer. Sure I could post all of her.

Comment: Was your problem solved?

Comment: I apologize, i've been extremely busy lately. I'll give it a shot when I get home later on. Thank you for the help, Ill post back here in the evening. Social networks are a lot of work for one person to complete... I'm starting to see that now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the main reasons why 'Infinite Scrolling' is used is to reduce the amount of data the needs to be sent initially when a page is loaded. I may be wrong but it looks like you have a single Gqlquery that loads all of a users posts. This doesn't really make much sense with the infinite scroll concept. If all of the posts are queried when the page is loaded there would be minimal, if any, benefit from not displaying them all initially.

Anyways, I would consider using a jQuery plugin such as [Infinite Scroll](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/infinite-scroll-jquery-plugin/) for this. Here's the basic concept.

First load the page and print whatever has been returned from the GqlQuery.

```
<html>
  <div id="posts">
    <div>post 1</div>
    <div>post 2</div>
    <div>post 3</div>
  </div>
</html>
```

Next use javascript to select the `<div id="posts">` element.

Then, load another set of posts (page 2) into an off-DOM `<div>`.

Finally, when someone has reached the bottom of the page, append the `<div id="posts">` element that you selected with the next set of posts (insert them below the final post in the `<div id="posts">` element).